# assigning casted pointer or memcpy

Tags: c++, memcpy, reinterpret-cast

Assuming memory to be perfectly aligned for the operation and `T` to be a basic type (`int`, `float`, `double`, ect), which of these operations would be more efficient on most compilers at maximum optimization level? :

```
void *memory = ::operator new(sizeof(T));
*reinterpret_cast<T*>(memory) = some_func();
```

or

```
void *memory = ::operator new(sizeof(T));
T i = some_func();
std::memcpy(memory, &i, sizeof(T));
```

Instinct tells us that the first would be faster (without the temporary value storage) but I'm sure a modern compiler would optimize this out.

I feel as though the first operation makes more sense logically (assigning a value to a location) but wouldn't be applicable for larger sets of data where multiple values need to be copied, but I just wonder for simple operations like my example.

**EDIT:**
Given my own circumstances I would never purposefully do something like this, but I am working with a third-party API that supplies a `malloc`ed buffer and all I want to do is modify the first four bytes so that an integer value is put there

Comment: The first one is flat-out UB. There's no object in the memory, you cannot magically pretend there is one.

Comment: The only "sane" construct (and that's stretching it) is `::new (memory) T(some_func());`, but why?

Comment: @KerrekSB no, it isn't. There is memory allocated in the address returned by `new` and one can treat that memory however one wishes (as long as there is enough space allocated).

Comment: @KerrekSB you would be correct if `T` were non-pod so I changed my question to specify that.

Comment: @KerrekSB as to why: I am working with an API that allocated memory into a buffer and I want to modify the first four bytes of the buffer and `reinterpret_cast<int*>(buffer)` seems much more "sane" than `memcpy()`

Comment: "Which would be more efficient on most compilers" is way too vague a question IMHO

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well, I'm developing this to be re-usable, so what do you think would be a better question? I even just think it would be interesting to find out, regardless of why I'm asking

Comment: Either is correct, it seems like six of one and half a dozen of the other. It seems more likely to me that the assignment will be faster (because not all compilers might optimize the memcpy) however that is based on no evidence whatsoever. You could look at assembly generated by compilers that you have on hand.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Without any optimizations two instructions are omitted in the cast version and in the fully optimized version the assembly is identical. I thought that may be the case.

Comment: "and one can treat that memory however one wishes (as long as there is enough space allocated)." No, you can't. This is only true for certain types (trivially copyable, IIRC). For any other types, if there is no object constructed there, no dice. About your question, the only way to know is by looking at the compiler's output.

Comment: @MattMcNabb you would be surprised, then.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I stated quite clearly in the question that it was for basic types, and I'm pretty sure basic types are trivially copyable :L

Answer (score 0):

when not put each example in a loop, run the loop 1,000,000 times and see which one is quicker.  Make sure you compile in release though ;)

Comment: I don't know why you got a down-vote for this, this is certainly the most sane answer. Testing is definitely the way to check! The assembly output is the same for both, so except for run-time differences they should run at the same speed.

Answer (score -1):

Assignment is a language construct which is visible to the compiler and can be optimized in a combination with the object construction in some_func(). memcpy() is an "isolated" function with a raw memory operation.

The first example will highly depend on the some_func() internals. Modern C++11/14 constructs include copy and move operations which can help the optimizer a lot.

Comment: Both the first **and** second examples will highly depend on `some_func()`s internals because it could spend 5 seconds doing something where the actual copying would take nanoseconds (trivial types)

Comment: `memcpy()` is a function that is part of C++ and the compiler is aware of it and thus can also perform optimization with it.